# PL/SQL cursor in the while

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is what I am trying to achieve:

1. define a cursor
2. which return me list of rows
3. use the rows to do some modify tables
4. repeat 2 and 3 until cursor returns no result.

this is what I have done so far

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS
    [My SQL HERE];

BEGIN

   FOR r1 in c1 LOOP
   [modify tables]

END;
```

question is where do I put the while? I would do it before the for loop. but whats the syntax in pl/sql to describe c1 has result?

Note after c1 fullly finish I need to rerun the cursor code. Make another iteration . Because the result will be different. That's why I needed the while

Comment: you should read the docs. Or use Google: [sql+for+loop+cursor](https://www.google.ro/search?q=oracle+pl%2Fsql+for+loop+cursor). To be more exact you need an `end loop`

Comment: @florin ghita indeed an universal answer for all stack overflow question can be "just google it" lol

Comment: Your question was missleading. See the answers. Anyone understood you need to make a loop. Just reread the cursor. It would contain new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is combine 'while' with 'for '. Obviously only if you want to run the cursor multiple times, because you are update/alter something inside the cursor, and the condition changed, thus you need to re-run the cursor again.

here is the basic structure:

```
 DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS
    [My SQL HERE];

BEGIN

   WHILE CONDITION LOOP

   FOR r1 in c1 LOOP
   [modify tables]
   END LOOP; -- for loop

   [Check The Condition]

   END LOOP; -- while loop

 END;
```

e.g

```
  DECLARE

  counts NUMBER := -1;
  CURSOR c1 IS
    [Statement Here];

BEGIN

   WHILE count != 0 LOOP

   FOR r1 in c1 LOOP
   [modify tables]
   END LOOP; -- for loop

   SELECT count(*) ...... INTO counts

   END LOOP; -- while loop

END;
```

Comment: +1 from me for finding yourself the answer. You just need a `loop` keyword after the `while condition`. However the question is really hard to respond, because were not clear what is asked.

Comment: I don't understand you. A while loop in PL/SQL looks like `while conditiion loop statements; end loop;`. [while in Oracle pl/sql](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/while.php)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend to think about conventional update without cursors because the best part of them is slower. I also don't understand what for you would like to replace FOR by WHILE. They work nearly similar. At any case the best source of advice is the documentation from Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems020.htm

Comment: Cursor select result set once then return all the rows , after using the rows to modify the tables. I need the cursor to select again. That's why I need a while

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate `WHILE`. The [`FOR ... LOOP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CIHCGJAD) will iterate over the rows returned by the cursor:

```
FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
    -- r1 is the current row from the cursor
END LOOP;
```

There are two ways to handle a cursor, so perhaps that's caused confusion; [the alternative](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#BABJIICC) is something like:

```
OPEN c1;
LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO r1; -- where r1 is declared
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    -- do something with r1
END LOOP;
CLOSE c1;
```

Personally I usually find the `FOR ... LOOP` syntax simpler.

Comment: Your solution is based on the cursor always return the same result. My problem is after the first full Iterations. Run the cursor again there will be a new set of results